# script to run windows update on hyper-V images

Tags: hyper-v, powershell, windows-update

I have over 10 hyper-v images that I use for testing various projects. Some I use often some less so.

It is a lot of work starting each of the machines individually to run windows update.

I was wondering  if there is a powershell script that could spin up each of the machines, run windows update on it and then close it down again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your VMs only include recent (Vista or later) Windows system, you don't need to actually start them to apply updates; you can do it directly to the offline .VHD files, by mounting them and using the `dism.exe` offline servicing tool; `dism.exe` has several features, one of which is the ability to apply patches to an offline Windows image or VHD file.

This very nice script should be able to automatically mount a VHD file, apply some updates to it and unmount it; I've not personally tested it, but looks like it should work:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/839ee6f0-196f-4ed7-ac55-8e753c5d5ebe

Answer (score 2):

Not that I am aware of. This functionality is built into SCVMM, a non-free produce MS sells.

You might be able to do some sort of homebrew script (if I remember tomorrow I've got scripts for doing some other maintenance similar to this and will post them).